# HTTPS decoding, SSL decryption

Tags: c#, ssl, https

I have a scenario where a TcpListner acts as proxy between client and server. The proxy needs to log all internet traffic. SSL encrypt all the html stuff.

Can I grab the key from the stream to the decrypt the SSL stuff ? 
If not, i can act as an SSL server. But where is the entry point? When the
server tell the client to use ssl ? I can not even see the html text just the headers
by encoding the stream from the server to ASCII.

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you're trying to do, what code you've written.  Also, it's unclear whether you're trying to *force* SSL or simply parse it when a page is encoded using SSL.

Comment: this is the kind of stuff ssl mitigates.

Comment: Two responses explaining everything were posted (by Iridium and Chris) while I was typing - I am not very fast typist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL is intended to be secure against man-in-the-middle attacks, hence you will not be able to extract the key to decrypt the traffic. If your application is acting as a proxy, the only cleartext that you're likely to receive will be the initial `CONNECT` request.

One option would be to do what a number of commercial firewalls do to permit SSL inspection, which is to impersonate the remote side of the connection to the client, establishing a separate SSL stream to each. To do this you'll need to do a number of things, and it will ***only*** work if you are able to install your own trusted root certificate on all clients that will use your proxy (e.g. using Windows group policy). If you can't do this, you might as well give up, as it makes what you're attempting to do effectively impossible.

1. Determine the name of the server that the client is connecting to from the `CONNECT` request.
2. Generate a certificate with the CN set to the server name established in step 1, signed by a root certificate trusted by the client.
3. Establish a network connection to the destination host, and using the .NET `SslStream` to wrap the connection and call `AuthenticateAsClient(...)`.
4. Again using `SslStream`, wrap the client's incoming network stream, and call `AuthenticateAsServer()` using the certificate generated in step 2.
5. Forward data between the two connections, logging it as you require.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it seems you have a client, a proxy in the middle, and a server. The client and server are using SSL to communicate, and you're wanting the proxy to decrypt the SSL-encrypted messages between the client and server.

First question then, is the server yours? If not, then this is exactly what SSL is supposed to prevent. Next time you buy something on the Internet with your credit card, think about what your ISP could be doing if what you're asking were possible - they could put a proxy between you and the webstore and decrypt your credit card number, and you'd never know.

Comment: Well it IS possible! Just install Fiddler, activate SSL Decryption (Fiddler Options) and start logging. You will see the  messages decrypted into plain text in no means.

Answer (score 0):

You can *only* decrypt an SSL packet if you have the private key. Look into [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) if you want to inspect or log internet traffic, or [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) for a practical way of understanding HTTPS decryption.